# IVsSingleFileGenerator equivalent for multiple files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, code-generation

I'm writing a custom tool for Visual Studio and am currently using the IVsSingleFileGenerator interface. This works for the most part, but now I'd like to generate more than one file output.

Does anyone know how do go about doing this? I'm really hoping there is just a different interface to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a Custom Tool to Generate Multiple Files in Visual Studio 2005

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/VsMultipleFileGenerator.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Adam Langley. It took a while to find it but you answered my question almost 4 years ago.